# Extracting data from a database into array

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I'm building an angular application, so I have a PHP script extracting the database data into a JSON when requested.

This is what I'm using to extract the data into an array:

```
$values = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($values, $row);
}        
json_encode($values);
```

But it gives no result.

After some testing, if I change `json_encode($values);` to `print_r($values);` it actually print the table array, here an extract:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
     [id]    => 4 
     [title] => Feel the Moment 
     [views]  => 6 
)
```

It seems the script is not creating a valid array.

Comment: I think you need to use mysqli_fetch_array()

Comment: try to check if data exists with `if( $result->num_rows > 0 ) { .... }`

Comment: mysqli_fetch — Alias for mysqli_stmt_fetch() and its REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: you are using "this" keyword,  $this->mysqli->query($query)). Are you using it in a class function?

Comment: I tried to change the script to simply echo the id, as follow: `echo $row['id']`; into my while loop (as it is in the while loop right now) and it echo all the database ids, plus a at the end `[]`

Comment: @RohitAwasthi I wrote it at the start: "This is the function (contained into a class) [..]"

Comment: okay. what you get by print_r($json);

Comment: Looks like a not a real question to me

Comment: If you say "problem is not into this script", then question is wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I did some more testing & applied some corrections to the question, but I'm still in trouble, can you please consider helping me again?

Comment: try to echo json_last_error() if its more than 0 - then its json ptoblem.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Yes, it's this: `5 - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` - If you notice, in the array generated, the comma between rows are missing

Comment: Run `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` after connect

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Nailed it! Now it works 100% - Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id";
    if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($query)) {
        $json = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $json[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
```

Comment: He is using musqli_* and mysql_fetch_assoc is for mysql_*

Comment: what is the difference between your and OP's query?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes you're right. Can i delete my answer?

Comment: You are the owner of the answer and its ur call weather to keep or delete.

Comment: This is not the only mistake. Are you able to write a **working** code? If so - go on with it, you can edit your answer. If not - better delete it.

Comment: The code is working, but in essence it is exact copy of the code from the OP, save for the minor cleaning. But it cannot be count as answer, as it doesn't answer the question. However, it's rather OP's fault

Comment: @YourCommonSense OK. So what should i do now?

Comment: Just keep it as is. There are worse answers, alive and happy. Nobody cares, actually

Answer (score -1):

Your while is not executing, probably because you don't have any returned values from database.

I tested this code and it works well:

```
$json = array();

$json[] = array(
    "id"        =>  1,
    "category"  =>  'a',
    "tags"      =>  't');
$json[] = array(
    "id"        =>  2,
    "category"  =>  'b',
    "tags"      =>  'tt');

echo json_encode($json);
```

The result is:

`[{"id":1,"category":"a","tags":"t"},{"id":2,"category":"b","tags":"tt"}]`

And you'd better use `mysqli_fetch_row` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Try to debug your code. You may use `var_dump($result->fetch_assoc())` to see if the query has some results.

Comment: I tried to change the script to simply echo the id, as follow: `echo $row['id'];` into my while loop (as it is in the while loop right now) and it echo all the database ids, plus a at the end `[]`